# Opening new window in WPF throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with two windows, MainWindow and Window2.
MainWindow was created by Visual Studio (and then modified by me).
I then right-clicked on my project and chose Add -> Window.
I modified the new window XAML and added a button to my main page with this click handler:

```
    private void OnTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tst = new Window2();
        tst.Show();
    }
```

Clicking on the button with that handler results in an exception being thrown:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The visual tree has been
>   changed during a 'VisualTreeChanged' event.'

The line that threw the exception is

```
tst.Show();
```

Obviously, I'm missing something basic, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: It only occurred to me when I updated my Windows 10 to Fall Creators Update Insider Preview version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[I think i know what is it. Maybe this will help you.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1732fe72-30ce-4cdb-b06f-a4becf0f2d72/when-debugging-i-cannot-open-any-forms-in-vs-2017-windows-10-build-16215?forum=wpf)
You can also try this

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General ->Uncheck: Enable UI
>   Debugging Tools for XAML

Comment: Well look at that. Starting without debugging works. It seems this is a bug in the debugger (hah!)

Comment: As did debugging without XAML tools